# Evaluate an expression from visual selection in Python

Tags: python

I'd like to be able to select a part of a line, send it to a python interpreter, and have the selection replaced by the expression result. The use case is for doing math in Markdown documents:

```
1. Text here and then an expression 12 * 200
   1. More text and then an expression 31 + 5
```

I'd like to be able to select only `12 * 200` and have it be replaced by the result of the multiplication.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Vim version with Python support (you can check that in `vim --version` or `:version` and see if you have `+python3` or `+python3/dyn`), then you can use [`py3eval()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#py3eval%28%29) to evaluate the expression inside Vim itself.

This should work:

```
xnoremap <Leader>p c<C-R>=py3eval(@")<CR><Esc>
```

(Note: This assumes Python 3. There are similar functions for Python 2 and there's also a `pyxeval()` that will work with either version. But I'd really recommend against using those, since Python 2 is EOL already.)

If you don't have Python support in Vim, then you can do this by using an external call to a Python interpreter. But this is more messy, since it involves escaping the arguments to the shell and you need the Python code to `print()` it back to you. But if that's what's available to you, then you can use this snippet to run it through an external `python3` interpreter:

```
xnoremap <Leader>p c<C-R>=trim(system("python3 -c ".shellescape("print(".@".")")))<CR><Esc>
```

The solutions use [`<C-R>`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-R) with the [expression register](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#quote%3D) to insert the result of an expression as the replacement. They use the default register [`@"`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expr-register) to access the text that was just deleted by the [`c`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#v_c) command.

Comment: For simple expressions like in OP, python isn’t even necessary :P

Comment: @Ben Yes of course! But the question was about Python, so I didn't go there... But yeah using `eval()` to evaluate in Vimscript would have worked just as well here.

Comment: Oi, just realized I'm not the only using the expression register for a bit of meta-polyglot-programming :P

Comment: To add to the comments above: In neovim, one may also use Lua with `luaeval()` if Python support is not available (I think Lua is buillt-in so it should always be there).  It doesn't work with vim, though, so its less portable.